# New Client needs help securing his website after getting hacked.. and I found this...

Tags: php, shell, security

So, what is this? I haven't really experienced too much as far as "hacking" goes. I've dealt and solved most problems with PHP applications and I understand about 70% of this code.

But here is what I found, a Web Shell by Boff?

[My code](http://pastebin.com/kZeGHAHC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say, but generally to exploit something like this there is a loop hole in an `include` / `require` which is including a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable that is not being filtered / checked.

IE:

```
include($_GET['page'] . '.php');
```

Which some people did / do to lessen the code, however, anyone could inject a URL here and it could write a new file etc.

To fix:

```
$page = !empty($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:index;

$whiteList = array('index', 'home');

if (!in_array($page, $whiteList)) {
    $page = 'index';
}

include($page . '.php');
```

But yea, this is just one way. I am sure there are many other methods as well.

Comment: well the site was running OSCommerce, so .... I guess this should be brought up to them?

Comment: Potentially. Just make sure you are running the latest version of OSCommerece or you probably won't get any help.

Comment: Includes are harder to exploit these days because "remote file includes" no longer work by default.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a remote administration tool, which could potentially be used as a back door.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you found a backdoor that the attacker is using to access your site.  But this is only a symptom of a much larger problem.  Is is likely that a web application or library that you have installed is vulnerable to attack.  Someone used [Exploit Code](http://inj3ct0r.com/) to drop this backdoor and unless you patch the site,  the attacker will just drop another backdoor.

Make sure everything is up to date. Try and install a Web Application Firewall like [Mod_Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/).